# Can other people connect to my MongoDB cluster if I do not add 0.0.0.0/0 IP address?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB for the first time and I'm not sure if other people can connect to my cluster. Is it necessary to add a 0.0.0.0/0 IP address for anyone who is not using my current IP address?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means everybody can access your DB if they have the Mongodb URI. It also makes sense to use this if you code on your local machine since private customers usually have dynamic IPs so you would have to change your IP all the time

Comment: The main protection should be done by user authentication, not by `bindIp`